# How to encapsulate script with inner @""@, with external @""@

Tags: string, powershell

I have a script that contains `@""@` inside it:

```
$myHtml = @" 
<html>
...
</html>
"@
```

I want to convert all this script as a string with `@""@` to a variable.

This is what I tried:

```
$string = @"

$myHtml = @" 
<html>
...
</html>
"@

"@
```

But I get an error:
[image]

I can do a workaround by reading the bytes from my string and convert it to ASCII:

```
# Read the entire file to an array of bytes.
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("path_to_my_script")
# Convert to a text assuming ASCII encoding.
$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes)
```

But I want to learn how to encapsulate script with inner `@""@` with external `@""@`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the string quote, to single quote instead of double quotes:

```
$string = @'

$myHtml = @" 
<html>
...
</html>
"@

'@
```

See [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1)